# Understanding proof that continuous image of connected is connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, connectedness

I am trying to understand the proof: *A continuous image of a connected space is always connected*.
This is how it goes:

> If $f:X\to Y$ is a surjective continuous map with $X$ connected, then we need to show $Y$ is also connected. Suppose $Y$ is disconnected. Then there exists a non-empty clopen subset $U\neq Y$ in $Y$. Since $f$ is surjective, $f^{-1}(U)\neq\varnothing,X$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(U)$ is clopen. This contradicts that $X$ is connected.$\blacksquare$

I understand everything in this proof EXCEPT why we supposed that $f$ is continuous **and** surjective. Our question is only about continuous maps so why did we assume that $f$ was continuous and surjective? What about if the map is continuous but not surjective, then this proof will not work?

Comment: Consider $\sin x$ as a mapping from the real line $X$ to $Y=[-1,1] \cup \{2\}$

Comment: You can say in general that if $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map with $X$ connected, then $f(X)$ (the image of $X$ under $f$) is connected. The same proof would work. The assumption that $f$ is surjective gives that $Y=f(X)$.

Comment: You mean $f(X)$ is connected (not continuous).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asserting that the image of $f$ is connected is asserting that $f(X)$ is connected. What happens in $Y\setminus f(X)$ does not matter. So, it is natural to assume from the start that $Y$ is just $f(X)$; in other words, that $f$ is surjective.